# Странности с закрытием PrintWriter в Java

Tags: java, io

Почему такой пример выполняется, не выдвавая никаких исключений.

```
PrintWriter os = new PrintWriter(System.out, true); 
os.close(); 
os.println("text");
```

Comment: Судя по исходникам, у вас должна быть ошибка NullPointerException. С чего вы взяли, что ошибки нет?

Comment: @AndrewBystrov, запускал и проверял

Comment: Приведите минималистичный и рабочий пример кода, который демонстрирует данное поведение. http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @AndrewBystrov,         
`PrintWriter os = new PrintWriter(System.out, true);`
        `os.close();`
        `os.println("text");`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`PrintWriter` не совсем обычный класс, если посмотреть документацию к классу, то увидим следующее:

> Methods in this class never throw I/O exceptions, although some of its constructors may.  The client may inquire as to whether any errors have occurred by invoking {@link #checkError checkError()}.

Т.е. он проглатывает все ошибки, связанные с вводом-выводом.